# Clustering One Column According To Some Other Columns Python

Tags: python, data-mining

I have a `Dataset` with columns `cat1` , `cat2` , `cat3` , `city`.
I want to get `cities` in some clusters.
Is it possible clustering `df['city']` according to `other` three columns?

Answer (score 1):

You can cluster the cats first, then, since each pack of cats corresponds to  a city, use the resulting labels to cluster the cities:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'cat1': [-1, -2, -1, 3, 2], 'cat2': [-2, -1, -3, 1, 2], 'city': ['London', 'Paris', 'Lyon', 'Washington', 'Rome']})
>>> # some pairs of cats are all negative,
>>> # some pics are all positive,
>>> # so we definitely got two clusters
>>> df
   cat1  cat2        city
0    -1    -2      London
1    -2    -1       Paris
2    -1    -3        Lyon
3     3     1  Washington
4     2     2        Rome
>>> X = df[['cat1', 'cat2']].values
>>> X # the cats
array([[-1, -2],
       [-2, -1],
       [-1, -3],
       [ 3,  1],
       [ 2,  2]])
>>> # cluster the cats and get their labels
>>> lab = KMeans(2).fit(X).labels_
>>> lab
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
>>> # use labels to cluster cities
>>> # London, Paris and Lyon have all-negative cats
>>> df['city'][lab == 0]
0    London
1     Paris
2      Lyon
Name: city, dtype: object
>>> Washington and Rome have all-positive cats
>>> df['city'][lab == 1]
3    Washington
4          Rome
Name: city, dtype: object
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i have a big dataset and i have all cities in all clusters.How can i fix that?

Comment: What does it mean to "have all cities in all clusters"? If the cities are unique, each city will belong to exactly one cluster (at least when clustering with k-means)

Comment: For example : I have 1200 of London , 1300 of Paris and...
How can  i dedicate one cluster to each city?

Comment: Clustering is _unsupervised_ learning: you can't force data into a particular cluster without modifying the data or the algorithm - the clustering algorithm decides everything on its own. Why do you have multiple Parises, though? Are there multiple arrondissements in your data? Or maybe time? If so, you could cluster pairs like `('Paris', 'summer'), ('Paris', 'winter')` with respect to the cats. Otherwise, having Paris in multiple clusters would mean that Paris can belong to any of these clusters - this is also possiblele.

Comment: Thanks . You re so good.So if i want to do that, do you suggest to do classification instead of clustering?